# receive SMS from a port

Tags: android, null, sms, port

I want to create app, that can receive `SMS` from port! but when run it, my `msg.getMessageBody()` returns null. How can I fixed it?

**manifext.xml**

```
<receiver android:name="data.SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:scheme="sms"
                android:host="*"
                android:port="4030"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

**Broadcast Receiver code**

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String SHORTCODE = "+9810004473";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    Object[] messages = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
    for(int n=0; n < messages.length; n++) {
        sms[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    }
    for(SmsMessage msg : sms) {
        if(TextUtils.equals(msg.getOriginatingAddress(), SHORTCODE)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS: " + msg.getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

My `Toast` show: `SMS: null`

Comment: There won't be a message body on a data SMS message. Use the `SmsMessage#getUserData()` method to retrieve the data, which will be in the form of a `byte` array, as shown in the accepted answer on the linked post above.

Comment: tnx! that's right!